# Data Collection and storage using Arduino

Tags: driver

I want to read data from sensors (both analog and digital sensors) and save it into SD card by using arduino. Is there any basic program that help me out in doing this as this is the first time I am using arduino boards

Comment: I recently put together a simple Arduino UNO based data logger plan for some teacher friends of mine to use in their classrooms: http://edwardmallon.wordpress.com/2015/12/22/arduino-uno-based-data-logger-with-no-soldering/ It can be jumpered together in a few minutes, and the code should give you a good starting point for adding your own sensors. Also check out Tom Igoes simple data logger code at the Arduino playground, which would also run fine on this logger if you want to read analog inputs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a product recommendation site, and this answer should not be taken as such.

Adafruit has produced a data logging shield for the Arduino that is open source licensed and has sample code: [Data-Logger shield](http://www.ladyada.net/make/logshield/). It can be purchased [here](http://www.adafruit.com/products/243) or you could build your own since it is open source.